# PHP mysql ordering rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, row

For example, I have a table which looks like this :

**id** | **name**

1 | Mike

2 | Adam

3 | John

4 | Sarah
...

Now, when I execute query `select * from table order by id desc` it will output something like this:

4 | Sarah

3 | John

2 | Adam

1 | Mike

Now what do I do if I want to move John's row up or down, or move Adam's row up or down ( with a MySQL query ( I need basic one, just to know from where to start )).

**My solution :**

First of all, I created another column named `orderID` which has the same value as id.

Here is an example which moves up a user:

```
 $query = "
 SELECT  (
    SELECT orderID 
    FROM test WHERE id = 'user id that i want to move up'
    ) AS user_order,
    (
    SELECT orderID 
    FROM test WHERE orderID > user_order 
    ORDER BY orderID 
    LIMIT 0,1
    ) AS nextUser_order
 ";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 $query = "
 UPDATE test SET orderID = IF(orderID='{$data[nextUser_order]}', 
                  '{$data[user_order]}', '{$data[nextUser_order]}')
      WHERE orderID IN ('{$data[nextUser_order]}', '{$data[user_order]}');
 ";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: I think the question is, why do you want John to be moved up or Adam down?  Is the information required to make that decision in the DB?   If it is sort by that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to switch IDs, or to order it by another column. That's the only way.

Comment: thanks, i updated my post with my opinion on how to do that, can you look if it will work?

Comment: why do you use uId - 1 in SELECT ?

Comment: is it possible or that will be an invalid query? ( i have not tried it yet ) ( i set it to '+' now )

Comment: invalid ... try `update table set uId = uId - 1 where name = 'John'`

Comment: well thanks i will try to solve my problem tomorrow because i'm tired today, and i will add my solution to my question ... i'm going to sleep now... thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `id` is **not** what you want to do. You never want to mess with your primary key especially because later down the road it would be easier (and take up much less space, one is an int the other a varchar) to reference your users using their id rather than their name from other tables, it is nice to have a field that you know will never change.

Make another field such as `order` as a `floating point` number.

When you move `foo` between `bar` and `foobar`, set `foo`'s `order` to the `average` of `bar` and `foobar`'s `order`.

Comment: thanks but i don't know if I understood you... btw i updated my question with my solution, can you see if it may help me?

Comment: I just woke up so I probably shouldn't be optimising any queries but if it works for you that is good and I can't imagine it being very slow. My solution is for if you want to move somebody more than just one space at a time.

Comment: no in my case it will move user only by one position at a time

Comment: thanks :) i changed it a bit to make it look better :), you can see the code on botton of my question

Answer (score 0):

You can put arbitrary values into an `order by` clause in a query, but none will work easily for a simple "move up/down a row" type things. You can force certain values to sort first or last, but not "put this value after that value, but let that value go into its natural place". You'd need to have an extra field to specify sorting order.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables aren't inherently ordered - they effectively behave like a "bag of rows". If you want the results in a specific order, you will need to sort them (using `ORDER BY ...`) when you pull them out of the bag -- otherwise, the SQL server will return them in whatever order it feels is easiest. (In this case, they're coming out in the reverse order you inserted them, but that's not guaranteed at all.)

Answer (score 0):

You should def be using another column which holds the order of the display. id is just a unique identifier. On a relational database moving up and down rows might result in a lot of queries because of the updates on the related tables so I stick with the idea of defining a special row for this purpose.